# Who is represented by the small pharaonic bust in the corner of Room 1 of the British Museum- the Enlightenment Gallery?

Tags: ancient-egypt

I've magnified the information plaque in the virtual tour, but can only make out a name that appears to begin with a "P" and end in a numeral "I".  Scrolling through the Wikipedia list of Pharaohs does not reveal any obvious matches. Perhaps the subject is not a Pharaoh, but then...who?  No clear matches in the online collection database, either.  A video of the AfterHours tour comes tantalizingly close, but misses the life-size (I assume) damaged, black bust.

Comment: I haven't found a contact link yet, but will keep searching.  Nothing in the catalog, though, stylistically, almost every statue looks more or less like Ramses II or Amenhotep.  The name in the magnified images also seems too long to be "Ptolemy I", too.

Comment: Thank you!  (and the Walking Camera, too)

Answer (score 8):

A little searching brought up a video walking tour of the museum room mentioned. This YouTube video on The Walking Camera channel shows what I assume is the bust in question [time [5:19]](https://youtu.be/xFwB06na2So?t=319), and the plaque beneath the bust labels the item as [Ptolemy I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy_I_Soter),  [time [5:30]](https://youtu.be/xFwB06na2So?t=330) , so it does start with a P and end with an I.

The label reads

[image]

---

> Ptolemy I.
> Egyptian, late 3rd century BC.
>
> Fragment of a basalt statue of Ptolemy I (305-283 BC), general of
> Alexander  the Great, who founded the Ptolemaic dynasty of Egypt,
> wearing a royal headdress with a protecting serpent.
>
> Said to have been found in the lining of a well in the Nile Delta.

---

The museum has more information concerning this particular statue [here](https://www.britishmuseum.org/collection/object/Y_EA1641),
and here is an image of the bust in question from [Wikimedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5b/Ptolemy_I_as_Pharaoh_of_Egypt.jpg)
[image]